# What frames are essential to a rep farm?

Tags: warframe

What frames are optimal to a rep farm? What frames will I need in order to better support my team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current meta is mandatory:

- 1 x Trinity
- 1 x Excal
- 1 x Support Frame
- 1 x Any Frame

Requirements for **Trinity**:

Trinity's role is to serve only two purposes. Instant heals, and instant energy. Abilities used are Energy Vampire and Blessing

- Max Range

  - Overextended
  - Stretch
- Energy Vampire

  - modded for minimum Duration

    - Fleeting Expertise
    - Transient Fortitude
- Max Strength

  - Blind Strength
  - Intensify
  - Transient Fortitude

Requirements for **Excal**:

The main damage dealer. Radial Javelin is the only used ability here.

- Max Range

  - Overextended
  - Stretch
- Max Strength

  - Blind Strength
  - Intensify
  - Transient Fortitude
- Cast Time

  - Natural Talent

Requirements for **Support Frame**:

- Many frame choices are available that can boost Excal's damage

  - Rhino/Prime w/ Roar
  - Ember/Prime w/ Fireball Frenzy augment mod

    - Most optimal in a rep farm, as most rep farms involve fighting Grineer and Grineer are weak to fire
  - Frost/Prime w/ Freeze Force augment mod
  - Volt w/ Shock Trooper augment mod
  - Saryn w/ Venom Dose augment mod
  - An additional Excalibur frame

Requirements for **Any Frame**:

Ideally, popular choices include loot altering frames, like Nekros, because in a rep farm, there are a lot of enemies being killed every second, so it is the most ideal use of the 4th slot.  Additionally, players will bring frames they need to level up, which also works.  The ideal reason for a 4th player is to increase the enemy levels as well as increase the number of spawns.

As some people in the comments below have requested, why is there no Nova? Nova is a great damage amp frame. She can turn tough to kill enemies into swiss cheese easily. The issue here is that an Excal with max strength and range can kill enemies faster than it take Nova to molecular prime enemies. Excal is an instaneous AOE damage that homes in on enemies.  Nova's Molecular Prime is a bubble that slowly expands outwards to be applied on opponents.

This makes Nova almost entirely useless. The 4th frame can be any frame, including frames to be levelled, but to be a part of a critical team it is not useful at all.

Another note.  A common misconception is that Mirage is a viable support frame with the Total Eclipse augment. Unfortunately that is not the case, as that damage bonus only applies to weapon damage, as opposed to warframe damage (from abilities).

Comment: You've got Transient Fortitude for Trinity on there twice bud

Comment: Why do you not even mention Nova? Now that DE fixed the rep given by Molecular Prime, it should be considered even more for rep farming.

Comment: Be it a bug or not, total eclipse does affect the damage done by radial javelin. I have experienced it in runs and the first comment on the [wiki entry](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Total_Eclipse) for eclipse even confirms it.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated.  Currently either a properly built Ember or Ash can drag a very weak team through multiple Draco rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, either a properly built Ember or Ash can drag a very weak team through multiple Draco rounds.

An Ember with a medium large range, medium strength, and high efficiency/duration can keep the enemies well suppressed (dead) while other frames capture points and revive each other.  Firequake helps as the knockdown will further hamper enemies.  A syndicate weapon (Red Veil or New Loka are best) procing will add to the mayhem handily.

Ash built with high range, high efficiency, negative duration and medium strength can spam Blade Storm all day long to the same effect.  Ash seems to suffer from less affinity gain then Ember (perhaps because of the clone kills or range) but he is still very effective at making a mess of Draco Grineer.  He will also not proc off syndicate weapons with Blade Storm.